# Interactive remove files listed with paths in text file

Tags: shell, text-processing, files, xargs

I am trying to interactively remove files listed with their paths in a text file.

The command I am trying is:

```
xargs rm -i <filelist.txt
```

The error I get is:

```
rm cannot remove 'directory1/directory2/filename.extension\r': No such file or directory.
```

I suspect the `\r` that has been added to the end of the filename is an indication of what is wrong, but I have no idea what it might mean.

I also tried:

```
xargs -rd '\n' --arg-file=filelist.txt rm -i --
```

with the exact same result.

Files are listed in `filelist.txt` in the format: `directory1/directory2/filename.extension`
where `directory1` is in the current directory.

Comment: first `cd ..` then run your command. You are effectively telling the machine to look for directory1 under directory1. That is where the confusion is coming from if you expressed your situation correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but going up one level means Linux cannot find directory1.  (I also had to change the path to filelist.txt, but that sill dd not work.  Interestingly, both commands result in the same error messages, with either directory as the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file list uses `CRLF` line endings, instead of standard `LF`, hence the `\r` in the error message. Try:

```
xargs -rd '\n' --arg-file=<(<filelist.txt tr -d '\r') rm -i --
```

(Assuming your shell has process substitution, i.e. ksh, bash or zsh.)

Comment: That almost worked.  It got rid of the \r error, but did not pause for me to respond to the interactive input.  I am somewhat confused as to how your command works, so I apologize for being so "needy".  Thanks for getting me close!

Comment: `cat` outputs the file contents, `tr -d` deletes the requested char (`\r`, i.e. `CR`) from the stream.

Comment: The second suggestion worked perfectly.  I'm not sure how many you feel is too many.  In my case it was under 100, and the command ran with no noticeable delay.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I added a link. The OS puts a limit on the number of arguments. On my current system it is a bit more than 2 millions.

Comment: @Mike See my edit for a more robust solution (assuming that your shell supports process substitution).

Comment: @Giles  Thanks for your suggestion.  I'd like to suggest you do not edit an accepted answer, deleting the accepted change, replacing it with a fix that the originator may or may not accept.  Seems to me you should restore the answer from L. Level, and post your recommendation as a new answer (not a comment).